# Merging JS array of objects

Tags: javascript, object, merge

Ok so I have two objects which i want to merge but was wondering what the best way is...

```
obj1 = [
         { 
           id: 123, 
           list: [ {id:1}, {id:2}, {id: 3} ]
         },
         {
           id: 456
           list: [ {id:99}, {id:98}, {id: 97} ]
         }
       ]


obj1 = [
         { 
           id: 123, 
           list: [ {id:1}, {id:4}, {id: 5} ]
         },
         {
           id: 456
           list: [ {id:99}, {id:100}, {id: 101} ]
         }
       ]
```

I would like to be able to call something like `merge(obj1, obj2)` and the result to look like:

```
resultObj = [
         { 
           id: 123, 
           list: [ {id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}, {id: 5} ]
         },
         {
           id: 456
           list: [ {id:99}, {id:98}, {id:97}, {id:100}, {id: 101} ]
         }
       ]
```

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: Have you tried something already? It's really just a matter of using some pretty standard loops or array operations such as `Array#forEach`, `Array#filter`, etc...

Comment: @t.niese no, it's not the same thing.

Comment: @CengizAraz I have removed the duplicate vote at the same time you wrote the comment.

Comment: I have managed to do it in the standard way of using loops but thought there maybe a new way (es6) but doesnt look like it

Comment: does the outer or inner objects contain some more properties?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yep they are abit more complex then the example i gave above

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach()` to group elements by id on first level and then also one more `forEach()` and `find()` to check objects in list and push to array or assign to existing object with same id.

```js
var obj1 = [{"id":123,"list":[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]},{"id":456,"list":[{"id":99},{"id":98},{"id":97}]}]
var obj2 = [{"id":123,"list":[{"id":1},{"id":4},{"id":5}]},{"id":456,"list":[{"id":99},{"id":100},{"id":101}]}]  
       
var result = []       
var arr = [].concat(obj1, obj2)
arr.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!this[e.id]) result.push(this[e.id] = e)
  else {
    var that = this;
    e.list.forEach(function(a) {
      var o = that[e.id].list.find(c => a.id == c.id);
      o ? Object.assign(o, a) : that[e.id].list.push(a)
    })
  }
}, {})    
     
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested hash table for same `id` property. This solution copies all properties in the objects.

```js
function merge(source, target, hash) {
    source.forEach(function (o) {
        if (!hash[o.id]) {
            hash[o.id] = { _: Object.create(null), data: { id: o.id } };
            target.push(hash[o.id].data);
        }
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (['id', 'list'].indexOf(k) !== -1) {
                return;
            }
            hash[o.id].data[k] = o[k];
        });
        if (o.list) {
            hash[o.id].data.list = hash[o.id].data.list || [];
            merge(o.list, hash[o.id].data.list, hash[o.id]._);
        }
    });
}

var array1 = [{ id: 123, list: [{ id: 1, a: 3 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] }, { id: 456, list: [{ id: 99 }, { id: 98 }, { id: 97 }] }],
    array2 = [{ id: 123, list: [{ id: 1, b: 4 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }] }, { id: 456, list: [{ id: 99 }, { id: 100 }, { id: 101 }] }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

[array1, array2].forEach(function (a) {
    merge(a, result, hash);
});
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```